# TypeScript/ES6: what is an ":" in the below context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I understand below two usages in TS/ES6.

1. Below, a variable `myname` of type `string` which is going to be constant(final) is declared.

   const  myname: string = 'abcd';
2. Below a variable/function `initialPath` is declared and is assigned a function body using the `=>` operator.

   const initialPath = ({pathRoot, myvar = '', locale = ''}) =>
   path.join(process.cwd(), pathRoot, myvar, locale.toLowerCase());

But I am not sure of the below usage, what is `:` in the below doing.

```
module.exports = {
  application: myname,
  myservicePostfix,
  loadablePath: ({pathRoot, myvar}) =>
    path.join(basePath({pathRoot, myvar}), 'loadable.json')
}
```

-> does `application: myname` mean that `application = myname` and application is of type  typeof(myname).
-> similarily what does `loadablePath:` above mean

Comment: This is just a [standard javascript object declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_objects#using_object_initializers). The `exports` object has an `application` field with a value of whatever the value of `myname` is, etc.

Comment: @ray - could post an answer clarifying about `loadablePath:`.

Comment: The semantics is the same. `loadablePath: (...) => {}` just defines that your export object has a property named `loadablePath` which is a function ...

Answer (score 0):

The thing your confused about is simply a **dictionary object**. Here is another example of an object like yours:

```
const object = {
    thing1: “hello”,
    thing2: 78,
    thing3: () => {console.log(“thing3 has been run!”)},
    thing4: [6, 3, 4, 1, 8]
}
```

As you can see, my `object` variable contains **four elements**, or things. Each of them can be called by writing `object.nameOfThing`.

In your instance, you have a **nested function** as an element, the one that is called `loadablePath`. That is very much the same as my `thing3` element, which runs its function whenever it’s called:

```
object.thing3()
// result —-> thing3 has been run!
```

In simple words, yes. Just as `object.thing1: “hello”`  means that `object.thing1 = “hello”`, `application: myname` means that `application = myname`.

This is simply a dictionary object and that’s as far as it goes. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's no TypeScript involved in your example. I get that some confusion may arise from the fact that TS uses colons to associate a type with a variable, but none of that is in play here. This is pure javascript.

In a javascript object literal, properties are declared with `key: value`:

```js
const myObj = {
  foo: "bar",
  num: 42,
  myField: true
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```js
const myObj = {};
myObj.foo = "bar";
myObj.num = 42;
myObj.myField = true;
```

The value can be any valid javascript type, including a function:

```js
function myFunction () {
  console.log('my function invoked');
}

const someObject = {
  someFunction: myFunction
}

someObject.someFunction(); // logs "my function invoked"
```

You can also use an arrow function:

```js
const myFunction = () => console.log('my function invoked');

const someObject = {
  someFunction: myFunction
}

someObject.someFunction(); // logs "my function invoked"
```

The arrow function above can be inlined in the object declaration:

```js
const someObject = {
  someFunction: () => console.log('my function invoked')
}

someObject.someFunction(); // logs "my function invoked"
```

Putting this all together using your example:

```js
// mocking these out because loadablePath references them
const path = { join: (...args) => args.join('/')}
const basePath = ({ pathRoot, myvar }) => path.join(pathRoot, myvar);

// declare the string constants referenced in your example
const myname = "Appy McApperson";
const myservicePostfix = 'My Service Postfix';

// module has to exist before we can assign it an exports property
const module = {};


module.exports = {
  application: myname,
  myservicePostfix,
  loadablePath: ({pathRoot, myvar}) =>
    path.join(basePath({pathRoot, myvar}), 'loadable.json')
}


console.log(module.exports.application)
// "Appy McApperson"


console.log(module.exports.myservicePostfix)
// "My Service Postfix"


console.log(module.exports.loadablePath({
  pathRoot: '/path/root',
  myvar: 'somepath'
})); 
// "/path/root/somepath/loadable.json"
```

Comment: You didn't cover the shorthand notation at play in declaring the `myservicePostfix` property